# Printing in micro scale

Tags: print-design

*I am sorry if this is not the right website.*

I need to print a chess board like drawing (black and white squares). I need the printing to be in micro-scale accuracy (+-50 micron). What kind of printing should I head for? any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest finding a printer that deals with medical packaging. I place a lot of very small DataMatrix codes on very small labels and they need to be very accurate to pass GS-1 quality control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 50 micron inkjet printer

[image]

This is the only product I've seen. 
It's not all in english. 
http://www.htdpmj.com/EN/acp_view.asp?id=201

> Can spray into the number: 1~5 Ink color: black, red, green, invisible
>   and other non pigment ink Max printing speed: 300m/min Model: R400-50
>   micron Product Description: **Acer 50 micron micro character inkjet**
>   **printer** for a variety of packaging industry labeling requirements,
>   compared with the 60 micron standard spray printing effect is more
>   precise, can be satisfied with the identification of smaller products.
>   High performance to price ratio, high market share, national service
>   coverage.